# Capture a Widget with OpenGL content under Qt5.5

Tags: opengl, qt4, qt5, porting

I need to capture a screenshot of a widget with OpenGL content (using SoQt 1.5.0 classes under Qt5.5), and to save it to a QImage. What I've tried so far is:

- using grabFrameBuffer from the QGLWidget class (which seems to be
  obsolete since Qt5): it results in a black area
- using grabFramebuffer from the QOpenGLWidget class: the capture doesn't even work and there's no area dedicated to it
- using renderPixmap from the QGLWidget
  class: it results in a white area

The problem seems to be located in this if condition (which used QGLWidget::grabFrameBuffer() under Qt4.8 and which we are trying to migrate to Qt5.5):

```
if(dynamic_cast<QGLWidget*>(rendererCourant->getNormalWidget()))
{
    ((QGLWidget*)rendererCourant->getNormalWidget())->updateGL();
    _image = ((QGLWidget*)(rendererCourant->getNormalWidget()))->grabFrameBuffer();
}
```

Does someone have a hint on the matter ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is call:

```
auto fb = QOpenGLWidget->defaultFramebufferObject();
```

This should be the framebuffer that then QOpenGLWidget will be drawing to and then you use OpenGL to grab what you need.